# Laravel 4 complex query with union/join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

can someone help me with this?

when the user sends message to administrator it will generate batch_id then when admins send message to user batch_id will be null.

below is the table structure.

```
messages table:
---------------------------------------------------------------
id  |  sender_id | recipient_id | batch_id | subject | content
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1        3            1          $2yQr       test     test
---------------------------------------------------------------
  2        3            2          $2yQr       test     test
---------------------------------------------------------------
  3        2            3                      test2    test2
---------------------------------------------------------------

users table
------------------------
  id   |  name   | role
------------------------
   1     admin1  | ADMIN
------------------------
   2     admin2  | ADMIN
------------------------
   3      user   | USER
```

in the records above. 
the message with the same batch_id is the message the user sends to admins
then the message with empty batch_id is the message that admin send to user.

the user should only see like this

---

```
id  |  sender_id | recipient_id | batch_id | subject | content
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1        3            1          $2yQr       test     test
---------------------------------------------------------------
  3        2            1                      test2    test2
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

what I have so far is

```
Select c.id,sender_id, recipient_id, subject, content, s.name as sender, r.name as recipient 
        from (Select id,sender_id, recipient_id, subject, content from messages where batch_id is null 
        union Select (Select b.id from messages b where b.id=a.id limit 1) as id, a.sender_id,a.recipient_id, a.subject, 
        a.content from messages a where a.batch_id is not null group by a.batch_id) as 
        c JOIN users as s ON s.id = c.sender_id JOIN users as r ON r.id = c.recipient_id where (c.sender_id =3 
        or c.recipient_id = 3)
```

the query above works as expected but they want me to use query builder or eloquent from laravel

can someone help me to use query builder or eloquent from the query above or maybe someone has a better query that is easy to convert to query builder or eloquent

I'm currently new to laravel

Thanks!

Comment: There is no PHP code here.

Comment: yeah. I'm trying to convert that query and use query builder or eloquent from laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I'll just answer my own question in case someone encounter this and might be help.

after digging some time I was able to convert the query and use query builder from laravel.

```
        $first = \DB::table('messages as a')->select(\DB::raw('(select b.id from messages b where b.id=a.id limit 1) as id'),'a.sender_id','a.recipient_id','a.subject','a.content')
                  ->whereNotNull('a.batch_id')->groupBy('a.batch_id');
        $second = \DB::table('messages')->select('id','sender_id','recipient_id','subject','content')->whereNull('batch_id')
                  ->union($first);
        $data_query = \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$second->toSql()}) as c"))
            ->select('c.id','c.sender_id','c.recipient_id','subject','content','s.name as sender','r.name as recipient'')
            ->join('users as s','s.id','=','c.sender_id')
            ->join('users as r','r.id','=','c.recipient_id')
            ->whereRaw('(sender_id =' .$id . ' OR ' . 'recipient_id ='. $id.')')
            ->whereRaw('(subject LIKE '. '"%' .$subject.'%"' .' OR ' . 'content LIKE ' . '"%' .$subject.'%")' )
            ->whereRaw('(s.email LIKE '. '"%' .$sender.'%"' .' OR ' . 's.name LIKE ' . '"%' .$sender.'%")' )
            ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for this solution  ,after using your solution i get error cause of Bindings parameters in where clause ,after using where raw  it worked fine with me.

Comment: I'm glad it helps.